# Using prepared statement to retrieve login test info to $row parameter

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I managed to achieve the result I wanted. After going over the PHP manual website yet another time. Personally I think that site makes things confusing for someone like myself that is trying to learn.

CODE (working):

```
<?php

    include_once "lib\password.php";
    //include_once "config.php";

    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "urlvaultdb");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    CRYPT_BLOWFISH or die ('No Blowfish found.');

    $Blowfish_Pre = '$2y$10$';
    $Blowfish_End = '$';;

    $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['myusername']);   
    $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mypassword']); 

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT salt, password FROM users WHERE username = ?");

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $myusername);

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $salt, $password);

    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

    $hashed_password = crypt($mypassword, $Blowfish_Pre . $salt . $Blowfish_End);

    if ($hashed_password === $password) {

        session_start();
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $myusername;
        header("location:index.php");
        exit;

    } else {

        echo "Wrong Username or Password";
        echo "<form action='index.php'>";
            echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Log-in'>";
        echo "</form>";

    }

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: i've been reading the php manual for a while now. I've read and followed other Stack Overflow posts that I found from google searching. I still haven't been able to find a solution. Also, its not random lines of code, I had this working perfectly with a normal mysql statement.

Comment: Thee is nothing particular in getting salts or passwords out of query - they are retrieved exactly the same way as any other data - just like in any example shown. And it *is* a random set of lines, with no particular meaning and connection between them.

Comment: its not about the salts/passwords im getting back. I mentioned them to give full background and explain what im trying to do. Obviously your not wanting to help, please dont comment in that case.

Comment: @Corey, what actually happens in your code when it gets to the IF statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this will help you but i do something very similar using PDO but it should be along the same lines.  I have a user enter their username and password and I use their username to get their user salt from the database.

For me, I prepend the salt to the users provided password then i hash it.  I then check to see if the password provided by the user along with the salt and hash matches the password in the database return true or false.

```
//Select users row from database base on $email
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :userfield OR email = :userfield LIMIT 1';

$array = array(':userfield' => $_POST['myusername']);

$sth = $this->prepare($sql);

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $sth->bindValue("$key", $value);
}

$sth->execute();

$selection = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//Salt and hash password for checking
$password = $selection[0]['user_salt'] . $_POST['mypassword'];
//hash the password
$password = $this->hashData($password);
// if there is a match return true otherwise return false
$match = ($password != $selection[0]['password'] ? false : true);
```

Comment: @Your Common Sense. Please dont continue reply here. This person made a decent an polite effort to help me. All you have done if make accusations and make unhelpful comments. Im not expecting or asking for "working code served on a golden plate", an explination on how I can solve my problem would be fine.

Comment: @Corey as I told you before, all the "explanation" you need is a tutorial to follow. Trying to use a new API without learning it first is a road to nowhere. It will produce either a fix you are in, or a code like in this answer.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, This was taken out of a function in my class and it allows for multiple keys/values to be added.  On this occasion only 1 key/value is used but he could add more if needed.  In fact he could have 10 and that would save 10 bindvalues (repetitive code)

Comment: That's quite weak an excuse for posting [bloated code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_bloat). Not to mention *again* that with PDO you never need no explicit loops at all.

Comment: Well let's see your example then instead of constant criticism of every question anyone asks.  All I see in your comments in any question is criticism and no answers

Comment: Oh, the explanation is fairly simple. Most of questions asked here are just plain offtopic (this very one is an example) - so, there is no point in answering them. Yet I answer on topic questions all right. Too bad, they are too rare to happen :(